# Web GL Globe not working locally

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-code, webgl-globe

I've been trying to get the Web GL Globe ( http://code.google.com/p/webgl-globe ) working. I downloaded the source code from the Google Code page and unzipped all the files to a single folder. The May 13th release is the latest as of writing.
However the index.html page loads without the globe in Chrome and other browsers. I had a quick look at the code but I'm new to javascript etc. It appears some of the references to files are incorrect as if I correct the line:

```
     background: #000000 url(/globe/loading.gif) center center no-repeat;
```

to

```
     background: #000000 url(../globe/loading.gif) center center no-repeat;
```

I get a loading wheel gif loading but spinning forever.

Looking further into the code it appears moving `globe.animate();` to a different line creates a working globe but without the data loading functionality.
I tried the following to get a globe displaying:

```
        globe.createPoints();
        settime(globe,0)();
      }
    }
  };globe.animate();
```

Basically I would love a working download (zip?) of the WebGL globe or someone to take a look at the download on http://code.google.com/p/webgl-globe/downloads/list and let me know how to create a working version from the broken code on the site.

Thanks in advance,

Charlotte

Answer (score 5):

Are you hosting this just by running it off the file system?  If you are then that is why the images aren't loading "/" will refer to your root directory.  If you are running on something that has python you can run the following from the project directory

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Then browse to http://0.0.0.0:8000/ and it should work.

[image: showing it working]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick reply. I tried this however the links are still all broken if I leave them in the same structure as the .zip file. Using the errors in the python terminal I was able to move everything to where it was expected to be and I'm not getting any 404 errors showing in the terminal anymore. However the problem with the eternal loading wheel remains. Could you by any chance attempt to get the code from http://code.google.com/p/webgl-globe/downloads/list and let me know if it works? I think it may just be the latest revision is bad and I can't get an old one.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest snapshot from that URL you gave, ran it from the root [and just ran it with screenshot].  I at first tried to run it from the "globe" directory - but that doesn't work you have to run python -m SimpleHTTPServer from the project directory (where the README.md is) - it takes a while to load but it does load.

Comment: Just run it from a wamp server if youre using Winblows

Answer (score 0):

If you just click on index.html, it would not work, because the js files would not be loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/globe/globe.js"></script>
```

For sure if you use for exemple MAMP (WAMP) and change your document root to /Users/You/Downloads/webgl-globe-master

You will just have to go there in order to load the js files without editing the html code :

```
http://localhost:8888/globe/
```